# UBL 2.1 XML deserialization C# list/array

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, ubl

I have trouble to deserialize part of invoice XML.

Tag cac:InvoiceLine is repeating.

I need help to make list/array for element InvoiceLine and do foreach loop and extract values from child elements.

This is example of XML file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<env:DocumentEnvelope xmlns:env="urn:eFaktura:MinFinrs:envelop:schema">
  <env:DocumentHeader>
    <env:SalesInvoiceId>4372797</env:SalesInvoiceId>
    <env:PurchaseInvoiceId>3935145</env:PurchaseInvoiceId>
    <env:DocumentId>3ff1e4d7-9025-4908-b05b-26094758bd7d</env:DocumentId>
    <env:CreationDate>2022-10-06</env:CreationDate>
    <env:SendingDate>2022-10-06</env:SendingDate>
    <env:DocumentPdf mimeCode="application/pdf"></env:DocumentPdf>
  </env:DocumentHeader>
  <env:DocumentBody>
    <Invoice xmlns:cec="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonExtensionComponents-2" 
    xmlns:cac="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonAggregateComponents-2" 
    xmlns:cbc="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonBasicComponents-2" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
    xmlns:sbt="http://mfin.gov.rs/srbdt/srbdtext" 
    xmlns="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:Invoice-2">
      <cbc:CustomizationID>urn:cen.eu:en16931:2017#compliant#urn:mfin.gov.rs:srbdt:2022#conformant#urn:mfin.gov.rs:srbdtext:2022</cbc:CustomizationID>
      <cbc:ID>24</cbc:ID>
      <cbc:IssueDate>2022-10-06</cbc:IssueDate>
      <cbc:DueDate>2022-10-20</cbc:DueDate>
      <cbc:InvoiceTypeCode>380</cbc:InvoiceTypeCode>
      <cbc:Note>PROD</cbc:Note>
      <cbc:DocumentCurrencyCode>RSD</cbc:DocumentCurrencyCode>
      <cac:InvoicePeriod>
        <cbc:StartDate>2022-09-01</cbc:StartDate>
        <cbc:EndDate>2022-09-30</cbc:EndDate>
        <cbc:DescriptionCode>35</cbc:DescriptionCode>
      </cac:InvoicePeriod>
      <cac:AdditionalDocumentReference>
        <cbc:ID>24</cbc:ID>
        <cbc:DocumentType>PRILOG 1</cbc:DocumentType>
        <cac:Attachment>
          <cbc:EmbeddedDocumentBinaryObject mimeCode="application/pdf" encodingCode="base64" filename="24.pdf"></cbc:EmbeddedDocumentBinaryObject>
        </cac:Attachment>
      </cac:AdditionalDocumentReference>
      <cac:AccountingSupplierParty>
        <cac:Party>
          <cbc:EndpointID schemeID="9948">123456789</cbc:EndpointID>
          <cac:PartyIdentification>
            <cbc:ID>81906</cbc:ID>
          </cac:PartyIdentification>
          <cac:PartyName>
            <cbc:Name>SUPPLIER NAME</cbc:Name>
          </cac:PartyName>
          <cac:PostalAddress>
            <cbc:StreetName>SUPPLIER STREET</cbc:StreetName>
            <cbc:CityName>SUPPLIER TOWN</cbc:CityName>
            <cbc:PostalZone>SUPPLIER ZIP CODE</cbc:PostalZone>
            <cac:AddressLine>
              <cbc:Line>STREET,TOWN, ZIP</cbc:Line>
            </cac:AddressLine>
            <cac:Country>
              <cbc:IdentificationCode>RS</cbc:IdentificationCode>
            </cac:Country>
          </cac:PostalAddress>
          <cac:PartyTaxScheme>
            <cbc:CompanyID>RS123456789</cbc:CompanyID>
            <cac:TaxScheme>
              <cbc:ID>VAT</cbc:ID>
            </cac:TaxScheme>
          </cac:PartyTaxScheme>
          <cac:PartyLegalEntity>
            <cbc:RegistrationName>SUPPLIER NAME</cbc:RegistrationName>
            <cbc:CompanyID>98765432</cbc:CompanyID>
          </cac:PartyLegalEntity>
          <cac:Contact>
            <cbc:ElectronicMail>xxx@xxx.rs</cbc:ElectronicMail>
          </cac:Contact>
        </cac:Party>
      </cac:AccountingSupplierParty>
      <cac:AccountingCustomerParty>
        <cac:Party>
          <cbc:EndpointID schemeID="9948">111111111</cbc:EndpointID>
          <cac:PartyIdentification />
          <cac:PartyName>
            <cbc:Name>CUSTOMER NAME</cbc:Name>
          </cac:PartyName>
          <cac:PostalAddress>
            <cbc:StreetName>CUSTOMER street</cbc:StreetName>
            <cbc:CityName>CUSTOMER town</cbc:CityName>
            <cbc:PostalZone>CUSTOMER zip</cbc:PostalZone>
            <cac:AddressLine>
              <cbc:Line>street, town, zip</cbc:Line>
            </cac:AddressLine>
            <cac:Country>
              <cbc:IdentificationCode>RS</cbc:IdentificationCode>
            </cac:Country>
          </cac:PostalAddress>
          <cac:PartyTaxScheme>
            <cbc:CompanyID>RS111111111</cbc:CompanyID>
            <cac:TaxScheme>
              <cbc:ID>VAT</cbc:ID>
            </cac:TaxScheme>
          </cac:PartyTaxScheme>
          <cac:PartyLegalEntity>
            <cbc:RegistrationName>CUSTOMER NAME</cbc:RegistrationName>
            <cbc:CompanyID>22222222</cbc:CompanyID>
          </cac:PartyLegalEntity>
          <cac:Contact>
            <cbc:ElectronicMail>yyy@yyy.rs</cbc:ElectronicMail>
          </cac:Contact>
        </cac:Party>
      </cac:AccountingCustomerParty>
      <cac:Delivery>
        <cbc:ActualDeliveryDate>2022-09-30</cbc:ActualDeliveryDate>
      </cac:Delivery>
      <cac:PaymentMeans>
        <cbc:PaymentMeansCode>30</cbc:PaymentMeansCode>
        <cbc:PaymentID>223985-2209</cbc:PaymentID>
        <cac:PayeeFinancialAccount>
          <cbc:ID>100-000000-11</cbc:ID>
        </cac:PayeeFinancialAccount>
      </cac:PaymentMeans>
      <cac:TaxTotal>
        <cbc:TaxAmount currencyID="RSD">967.2</cbc:TaxAmount>
        <cac:TaxSubtotal>
          <cbc:TaxableAmount currencyID="RSD">9464</cbc:TaxableAmount>
          <cbc:TaxAmount currencyID="RSD">946.4</cbc:TaxAmount>
          <cac:TaxCategory>
            <cbc:ID>S</cbc:ID>
            <cbc:Percent>10</cbc:Percent>
            <cac:TaxScheme>
              <cbc:ID>VAT</cbc:ID>
            </cac:TaxScheme>
          </cac:TaxCategory>
        </cac:TaxSubtotal>
        <cac:TaxSubtotal>
          <cbc:TaxableAmount currencyID="RSD">104</cbc:TaxableAmount>
          <cbc:TaxAmount currencyID="RSD">20.8</cbc:TaxAmount>
          <cac:TaxCategory>
            <cbc:ID>S</cbc:ID>
            <cbc:Percent>20</cbc:Percent>
            <cac:TaxScheme>
              <cbc:ID>VAT</cbc:ID>
            </cac:TaxScheme>
          </cac:TaxCategory>
        </cac:TaxSubtotal>
      </cac:TaxTotal>
      <cac:LegalMonetaryTotal>
        <cbc:LineExtensionAmount currencyID="RSD">9568</cbc:LineExtensionAmount>
        <cbc:TaxExclusiveAmount currencyID="RSD">9568</cbc:TaxExclusiveAmount>
        <cbc:TaxInclusiveAmount currencyID="RSD">10535.2</cbc:TaxInclusiveAmount>
        <cbc:AllowanceTotalAmount currencyID="RSD">0</cbc:AllowanceTotalAmount>
        <cbc:PrepaidAmount currencyID="RSD">0</cbc:PrepaidAmount>
        <cbc:PayableAmount currencyID="RSD">10535.2</cbc:PayableAmount>
      </cac:LegalMonetaryTotal>
      <cac:InvoiceLine>
        <cbc:ID>1</cbc:ID>
        <cbc:InvoicedQuantity unitCode="MTQ">65</cbc:InvoicedQuantity>
        <cbc:LineExtensionAmount currencyID="RSD">3971.5</cbc:LineExtensionAmount>
        <cac:Item>
          <cbc:Name>line 1 description</cbc:Name>
          <cac:SellersItemIdentification>
            <cbc:ID>1</cbc:ID>
          </cac:SellersItemIdentification>
          <cac:ClassifiedTaxCategory>
            <cbc:ID>S</cbc:ID>
            <cbc:Percent>10</cbc:Percent>
            <cac:TaxScheme>
              <cbc:ID>VAT</cbc:ID>
            </cac:TaxScheme>
          </cac:ClassifiedTaxCategory>
        </cac:Item>
        <cac:Price>
          <cbc:PriceAmount currencyID="RSD">61.1</cbc:PriceAmount>
          <cbc:BaseQuantity unitCode="MTQ">1</cbc:BaseQuantity>
        </cac:Price>
      </cac:InvoiceLine>
      <cac:InvoiceLine>
        <cbc:ID>2</cbc:ID>
        <cbc:InvoicedQuantity unitCode="MTQ">65</cbc:InvoicedQuantity>
        <cbc:LineExtensionAmount currencyID="RSD">2535</cbc:LineExtensionAmount>
        <cac:Item>
          <cbc:Name>line 2 description</cbc:Name>
          <cac:SellersItemIdentification>
            <cbc:ID>3</cbc:ID>
          </cac:SellersItemIdentification>
          <cac:ClassifiedTaxCategory>
            <cbc:ID>S</cbc:ID>
            <cbc:Percent>10</cbc:Percent>
            <cac:TaxScheme>
              <cbc:ID>VAT</cbc:ID>
            </cac:TaxScheme>
          </cac:ClassifiedTaxCategory>
        </cac:Item>
        <cac:Price>
          <cbc:PriceAmount currencyID="RSD">39</cbc:PriceAmount>
          <cbc:BaseQuantity unitCode="MTQ">1</cbc:BaseQuantity>
        </cac:Price>
      </cac:InvoiceLine>
    </Invoice>
  </env:DocumentBody>
</env:DocumentEnvelope>
```

I generated classes in Visual Studio

1 Copy XML data to the clipboard

2 In VS, Edit > Paste Special > "Paste Xml as classes"

This is my code for get all other values from xml.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XmlSerializer serializer =
            new XmlSerializer(typeof(XmlStr.DocumentEnvelope));
            // Declare an object variable of the type to be deserialized.
            XmlStr.DocumentEnvelope envelope;
            using (Stream reader = new FileStream(@"C:\\Users\\Desktop\\24.xml", FileMode.Open))
            {
                // Call the Deserialize method to restore the object's state.
                envelope = (XmlStr.DocumentEnvelope)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
            }
            // Write out the properties of the object.
            Console.WriteLine(envelope.DocumentBody.Invoice.ID.Value);
        }
```

When I use code below, I get error

System.InvalidOperationException: 'There is an error in XML document (2, 2).'

Inner Exception

InvalidOperationException: `<DocumentEnvelope xmlns='urn:eFaktura:MinFinrs:envelop:schema'>` was not expected.

```
XmlSerializer serializer =
           new XmlSerializer(typeof(zaglavlje.InvoiceLine[]));
            // Declare an object variable of the type to be deserialized.
            zaglavlje.InvoiceLine[] envelope;
            using (Stream reader = new FileStream(@"C:\\Users\\Desktop\\24.xml", FileMode.Open))
            {
                // Call the Deserialize method to restore the object's state.
                envelope = (zaglavlje.InvoiceLine[])serializer.Deserialize(reader);
            }
            // Write out the properties of the object.
            //Console.WriteLine(envelope);
```

I would like to get InvoiceLine like this

**First loop**
ID: 1
InvoicedQuantity: 65
LineExtensionAmount: 3971.5
Item.Name: line 1 description
Price.PriceAmount: 61.1
BaseQuantity: 1
**Second loop**

ID: 2
InvoicedQuantity: 65
LineExtensionAmount: 2535
Item.Name: line 2 description
Price.PriceAmount: 39
BaseQuantity: 1

Comment: Can you elaborate on how your code "doesn't work"? What were you expecting, and what actually happened? If you got an exception/error, post the line it occurred on and the exception/error details which can be done with a [mre]. Please [edit] your question to add these details into it or we may not be able to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a customer serialization :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.Xml.Schema;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(FILENAME);
            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(DocumentEnvelope));
            DocumentEnvelope envelope = (DocumentEnvelope) serializer.Deserialize(reader);
        }
    }
    [XmlRoot(Namespace = "urn:eFaktura:MinFinrs:envelop:schema")]
    public class DocumentEnvelope
    {
        public DocumentBody DocumentBody { get; set; }
    }
    public class DocumentBody
    {
        [XmlElement(Namespace = "urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:Invoice-2")]
        public Invoice Invoice { get; set; }
    }
    public class Invoice
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "InvoiceLine", Namespace = "urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonAggregateComponents-2")]
        public List<InvoiceLine> InvoiceLine { get; set; }
    }
    public class InvoiceLine : IXmlSerializable
    {
        public int InvoicedQuantity { get; set; }
        public decimal LineExtensionAmount { get; set; }
        public string ItemName { get; set; }
        public decimal PriceAmount { get; set; }
        public decimal  BaseQuantity { get; set; }

        public void WriteXml(XmlWriter writer)
        {
            
        }

        public void ReadXml(XmlReader reader)
        {
            XElement invoiceLine = (XElement)XElement.ReadFrom(reader);
            XNamespace ns = invoiceLine.Name.Namespace;


            InvoicedQuantity = (int)invoiceLine.Elements().Where(x => x.Name.LocalName == "InvoicedQuantity").First();
            LineExtensionAmount = (decimal)invoiceLine.Elements().Where(x => x.Name.LocalName == "LineExtensionAmount").First();
            ItemName = (string)invoiceLine.Descendants().Where(x => x.Name.LocalName == "Name").FirstOrDefault();
            PriceAmount = (decimal)invoiceLine.Descendants().Where(x => x.Name.LocalName == "PriceAmount").FirstOrDefault();
            BaseQuantity = (decimal )invoiceLine.Descendants().Where(x => x.Name.LocalName == "BaseQuantity").FirstOrDefault();
        }
        public XmlSchema GetSchema()
        {
            return (null);
        }

    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @jdweng
I tried your code and works perfectly.

I also managed to adapt my code to get the count for InvoiceLine and do for loop.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{

    XmlSerializer serializer =
    new XmlSerializer(typeof(zaglavlje.DocumentEnvelope));
    // Declare an object variable of the type to be deserialized.
    zaglavlje.DocumentEnvelope envelope;
    using (Stream reader = new FileStream(FILENAME, FileMode.Open))
    {
        // Call the Deserialize method to restore the object's state.
        envelope = (zaglavlje.DocumentEnvelope)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
    }

    int xxx = envelope.DocumentBody.Invoice.InvoiceLine.Count();
    for (int i = 0; i < xxx; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("No: " + envelope.DocumentBody.Invoice.InvoiceLine[i].ID.Value);
        Console.WriteLine("Name: " + envelope.DocumentBody.Invoice.InvoiceLine[i].Item.Name);
    }
}
```